# How do I implement the Wix Velo cancelOrder() API reference to my site?

Tags: javascript, backend, velo

Here's the API reference:
https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-pricing-plans-backend/orders/cancelorder

I want to allow my customers to cancel their subscriptions by themselves.

Here's an example from another user:
[Possible security concerns with subscription handling in my Wix site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429840/possible-security-concerns-with-subscription-handling-in-my-wix-site/77761875)

@Letal1s just doesn't share their backend module (probably for private reasons).

I'm simply asking for help on how to let my members cancel their subscription with an `onClick` function.